# How to set up a Sidekiq Job to run every ten minutes until 23:59

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq

I have this job set up in sidekiq to run every 10 minutes every day.

The problem is that I need it to run at 23:59 instead of running at 00:00.
Is it possible to specify this exception in cron?

```
monitored_place_worker:
  cron: '*/10 * * * *'
  class: 'MonitoredPlacePoolWorker'
  queue: default
  active_job: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two scheduler rules. One - almost the same as yours:
`cron: '*/10 0-23 * * *'` but for hours 0 through 23.

And the second rules for past 23th hour like this
`cron: 0,10,20,30,40,50,59 23 * * *`